# Set permissions for files

Tags: permissions

the results of

```
ls -l
```

are:

```
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root    195,   0 Aug 30 14:59 nvidia0
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root    195, 255 Aug 30 14:59 nvidiactl
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root    195, 254 Aug 30 14:59 nvidia-modeset
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root    244,   0 Aug 30 14:59 nvidia-uvm
```

I'm trying to figure out how to comply with these instructions but I am a newby, not sure how to convert from letters to numbers and how to run this bash. Please send me some info so I can comply with below instructions:

> Check that the device files/dev/nvidia* exist and have the correct
>   (0666) file permissions. These files are used by the CUDA Driver to
>   communicate with the kernel-mode portion of the NVIDIA Driver.
>   Applications that use the NVIDIA driver, such as a CUDA application or
>   the X server (if any), will normally automatically create these files
>   if they are missing using the setuidnvidia-modprobe tool that is
>   bundled with the NVIDIA Driver. However, some systems disallow setuid
>   binaries, so if these files do not exist, you can create them manually
>   by using a startup script such as the one below:

```
> #!/bin/bash
> 
> /sbin/modprobe nvidia
> 
> if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then   # Count the number of NVIDIA controllers
> found.   NVDEVS=`lspci | grep -i NVIDIA`   N3D=`echo "$NVDEVS" | grep
> "3D controller" | wc -l`   NVGA=`echo "$NVDEVS" | grep "VGA compatible
> controller" | wc -l`
> 
>   N=`expr $N3D + $NVGA - 1`   for i in `seq 0 $N`; do
>     mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidia$i c 195 $i   done
> 
>   mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidiactl c 195 255
> 
> else   exit 1 fi
> 
> /sbin/modprobe nvidia-uvm
> 
> if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then   # Find out the major device number used by
> the nvidia-uvm driver   D=`grep nvidia-uvm /proc/devices | awk '{print
> $1}'`
> 
>   mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidia-uvm c $D 0 else   exit 1 fi
```

Read more at: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ixzz4IrZwBh1k
Follow us: @GPUComputing on Twitter | NVIDIA on Facebook

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: I'm asking 1. are my permissions correct and 2. if not how do I run the bash code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal like this... While holding down Ctrl and Alt keys, press t. A window will open. That's your terminal. In the terminal type gedit and press enter. A second window will open. Copy the script above into that second window and click the save button. Type the name "startup" in the Name: field and click the save button. Close that window. In your first window, the terminal, type chmod 755 startup and press enter. Now type ./startup and press enter. Your script will run.